# In Jekyll, how does include_relative work with respect to layout files?

Tags: include, jekyll, relative-path

I have a file called `default.html` in my `layouts` folder. In `default.html`, I want to add a relative `include` to `test.html`, which is also in my layouts folder.

I add `{% include_relative test.html }%` in my `default.html` file to include `test.html`. However, when I do this, I get an error that says

```
"Liquid Exception: Included file './test.html' not found in
projects/[projectnmae]/layouts/default.html"
```

I do have my `layouts` folder in a different location, as specified in my configuration file. Any ideas if `include_relative` works in a special way here that I'm not grasping?

Comment: Check the file name. Maybe it's certainly **tests.html**

Comment: No, I don't have a typo in the filename. I think this is a bug with Jekyll.

Comment: This can then be very interesting to see you code. Any github repo ?

Comment: Sure. Here's the repo: [https://github.com/tomjohnson1492/jekyll-doc](https://github.com/tomjohnson1492/jekyll-doc).

Comment: I don't think it's a theme issue, though. I replicated the issue using a new jekyll site. In this github repo, I'm trying to put everything related to one site into a specific project folder. The _includes folder is the only thing I couldn't move there.

Comment: Well, if you reproduce this bug on a new jekyll site, it will be easier to spot it. Can you push the code on a github for examination ?

Comment: The project is extremely simple. There are just a few steps to reproduce the bug. I uploaded it as a zip file here: http://idratherbewriting.com/test123.zip.  Just run `jekyll serve` and you'll see the error. Edit default.html to remove test.html and the error goes away.

Answer (score 10):

You can't use the `include_relative` tag with any files inside your layouts folder. You can only use `include_relative` on a page or post.

Answer (score 5):

Layouts code is executed in the context of page/post rendering and the `include_relative` is calculated relative to this page or post, not from the layout itself.

Tracking this error in debugger shows that `include_relative` tries to load `/home/user/www/test/_posts/test.html` and not `/home/user/www/test/_layouts/test.html`