# Jekyll: Include a file from directory outside of _includes

Tags: include, jekyll

I have an directory called `/patterns` in my Jekyll site, whose structure generally looks generally like this:

`_includes
_layouts
_site
/patterns
index.html`

I need to keep the `/patterns` directory outside `_includes` for a number of reasons, but mostly because I need to pull the files in `/patterns` into an iframe to display in a pattern library).

I'd like to include files from `/patterns` in my Jekyll pages, but using `{% include /patterns/file.html %} doesn't work as it points to the`_includes`folder. How would I go about including a file from a directory that isn't`_includes`?

Answer (score 10):

You can choose to [*include file fragments relative to the current
 file*](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/#including-files-relative-to-another-file) by using the `include_relative` tag for your
 `/patterns/file.html`

[image]

For the directory structure you have:

```
_includes
_layouts
_site
/patterns/file.html
index.html
```

In this case the following doesn't work:

```
{% include /patterns/file.html %}
```

Use `include_relative` as `/pattern` **is relatif** to `index.html` as the `current file`:

```
{% include_relative patterns/file.html %}
```

**Note**:

You can't use the `include_relative` tag with any files inside your layouts folder. You can only use `include_relative` on a page or post. Layouts code is executed in the context of page/post rendering and the include_relative is calculated relative to this page or post, [not from the layout itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28617211/in-jekyll-how-does-include-relative-work-with-respect-to-layout-files).

In this case your code on `index.html` shall be:

```
---
layout: null
---
(put all code from _layouts/default.html)
{% include_relative patterns/file.html %}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can change the directory that the `include` tag uses with `includes_dir` in your `_config.yml`. It doesn't look like you can set multiple paths (source: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/).

In any case, the files in `_includes` don't end up in your output. You could separate pattern-specific includes into `_includes/patterns/`, but the only thing that'd have any effect on your live site would be where those files were included.

Answer (score 4):

I think that [collections](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) will do what you need. They can be included and rendered as public html.

Here's an [example project](https://github.com/benubois/jekyll-collection) that does just this.

Comment: Thanks for this! I may be mistaken, but I think that prefixing the directory with an `_` means that Jekyll won't include that directory in `_site` when it compiles. For my use case, I need to include `/patterns` in `/_site` because I'm referencing those files in an iframe.

Comment: Generally that is true about the underscore, however collections have a special option to write out publicly accessible html as well. I encourage you to download the sample project and run `jekyll build` to see how it works.

Comment: Also if you open the index.html file you can see how to include it both in liquid and in an iframe.

Answer (score 3):

I put a symlink in place of the `_includes` directory that points where I want, since `includes_dir` doesn't seem to like `../` to specify a relative (one or more directories higher) path.

Comment: Does not work with Jekyll 3.8.5 and results in this error message `Ensure it exists in one of those directories and, if it is a symlink, does not point outside your site source.`

Answer (score 2):

I [improved the plugin](https://github.com/mslinn/jekyll-flexible-include-plugin) that @Jeremy Lynch referred to. Here is the documentation:

### `include_absolute`

Jekyll's built-in `include` tag does not support including files outside of the `_includes` folder.
This plugin supports 4 types of includes:

1. Absolute filenames (start with `/`).
2. Filenames relative to the top-level directory of the Jekyll web site (Do not preface with `.` or `/`).
3. Filenames relative to the user home directory (preface with `~`).
4. Executable filenames on the `PATH` (preface with `!`).

#### Syntax:

```
{% include_absolute path [ optionalParam1='yes' optionalParam2='green' ] %}
```

The optional parameters can have any name.
The included file will have parameters substituted.

#### Installation

Copy `include_absolute.rb` into `/_plugins` and restart Jekyll.

#### Examples

1. Include files without parameters; all four types of includes are shown.

   ```
   {% include_absolute '../../folder/outside/jekyll/site/foo.html' %}
   {% include_absolute 'folder/within/jekyll/site/bar.js' %}
   {% include_absolute '/etc/passwd' %}
   {% include_absolute '~/.ssh/config' %}
   ```
2. Include a file and pass parameters to it.

   ```
   {% include_absolute '~/folder/under/home/directory/foo.html' param1='yes' param2='green' %}
   ```

Comment: I tried it but plugin does not working ... https://github.com/mslinn/jekyll-flexible-include-plugin/issues/2 ... What is wrong did I do?

Comment: The issue you opened at the URL you gave is sufficient, no need to repost here. As I said in my response, possible reasons for this error message are:

 -   A directory called assets/js, based at the top of your Jekyll project, does not exist
 -   The directory exists but does not contain a file called my.js
 -   The directory and/or file lacks read permission.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the root folder that `include` looks for files under to the root of your site by adding the following to `_config.yml`

```yaml
include_dir: "."
```

You will then need to change any existing `include` calls to prefix the path with `_includes/`. For example:

```markdown
{% include an_include.html %}
```

should become:

```markdown
{% include _includes/an_include.html %}
```

Once done, you can then include files from under `patterns` using:

```markdown
{% include patterns/file.html %}
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the plugins referenced in other answers worked.
So here's my plugin in 20 lines that did work for me:

```
class RootInclude < Liquid::Tag
  def initialize(_tag_name, markup, _parse_context)
    super
    @markup = markup.strip
  end

  def render(context)
    expanded_path = Liquid::Template.parse(@markup).render(context)
    root_path = File.expand_path(context.registers[:site].config['source'])
    final_path = File.join(root_path, expanded_path)
    read_file(final_path, context)
  end

  def read_file(path, context)
    file_read_opts = context.registers[:site].file_read_opts
    File.read(path, **file_read_opts)
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('root_include', RootInclude)
```

Create a folder called `_plugins` in the root of your project if you don't already have one. Then place a file there with this content. Then restart Jekyll.

Now in your pages, layouts and includes you can do this:

```
{%- root_include assets/blocks/code-sample.html -%}
```

or this:

```
{%- root_include /assets/blocks/code-sample.html -%}
```

or this:

```
{%- root_include ./assets/blocks/code-sample.html -%}
```

They're all the same.

If you have a post with front matter like this:

```
title: "My Post"
code:  /assets/blocks/code-sample.html
---
```

You can then do this:

```
{%- root_include {{ page.code }} -%}
```

If you have a post with front matter like this:

```
title: "My Post"
code:  code-sample.html
---
```

You can then do this:

```
{%- root_include /assets/blocks/{{ page.code }} -%}
```

After 7 years I find it incredible that such a basic use-case is still unsupported by Jekyll. I wanted exactly the same as Brad. I wanted to have a code-snippet in a single place, that I could both `include` and make available through an `iframe`. For whoever is interested, this is a simplified version of what I'm using:

```
{%- assign block_path = page.block.path | prepend: '/assets/blocks/' -%}
<div class="block-embed">
  <iframe src="{{ block_path }}" sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
  <a href="{{ block_path }}" target="_blank" class="open-new-tab-link">{%- include icons/new-tab.svg -%}</a>
</div>

<div class="block-source">
  {% highlight html linenos %}
    {%- root_include {{ block_path }} -%}
  {% endhighlight %}
</div>
```

I shouldn't need a custom plugin for this. It's just infuriating. I probably should just migrate to bridgetownrb.

Answer (score -1):

In your _config.yml, you can add additional directories like so:

```
includes:
- patterns
```

Just as simple as that!

In action here on my Jekyll site: https://github.com/pschfr/pschfr.github.io/blob/master/_config.yml

Comment: Great! If I set that option, will `/patterns` still compile and show up in `/_site`?

Comment: If you put an index.html within `/patterns`, I believe so!

Comment: Hmmm, here's what I'm getting when I add your recommendation to my `_config.yml`: `Liquid Exception: Included file '_includes/patterns/file-name.html' not found`.
 
To be clear, I'm trying to include the file like: `{% include /patterns/file-name.html %}` Maybe I'm doing that wrong?

Comment: @BradFrost I think you need to remove the folder from the file path: `{% include file-name.html %}`

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Unfortunately it still looks like it's looking in `_includes`: `Error:  Included file '_includes/file-name.html' not found` is the error I'm getting.

Comment: The `includes` setting is actually called `include`, and does not set additional folders for the `{% include %}` tag. It includes otherwise-excluded files/folders in the output. See https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/

Comment: @pschfr Can you show where you are calling an include from outside the _includes dir on your site? I'd like to see an example of how you are doing this, but can't see one. Thanks.

Comment: ^ they aren't including anything outside the `_includes` dir. clone the linked website and `grep -r '{%.\?include'`, it's only ever including `head.html`, `header.html`, `contact.html`, and `footer.html` which are all in the `_includes` dir

Answer (score -1):

The ONLY solution I have found for this is to use this plugin

https://github.com/tnhu/jekyll-include-absolute-plugin

Answer (score -1):

this should be help https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/

```
include_dir: ./pattern
```