# Inline CSS while still using the default directory structure

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a standard Jekyll setup and use sass to compile some CSS. But I can't figure out how to inline the compiled CSS while still using the default directory structure. Current I have this code in my `_includes/head.html` file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/normalize.css" | relative_url }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/milligram.css" | relative_url }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ "/assets/foobar.css" | relative_url }}">
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
_sass
├── milligram
│   ├── _Base.sass
│   ├── _Blockquote.sass
│   ├── _Button.sass
│   ├── _Code.sass
│   ├── ...
└── milligram.sass
assets
├── milligram.scss
├── normalize.css
└── foobar.css
```

How can I do something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
  {% include normalize.css %}
  {% include milligram.css %}
  {% include foobar.css %}
</style>
```

Which doesn't work in the default directory structure because all those files are not in the `_includes` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the assets folder to the include option in your `_config.yaml` [configuration file](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/)?

`include:
  - assets`

It's a slightly different question and usage but there's a few other things you can try over at [Jekyll: Include a file from directory outside of _includes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39734133/jekyll-include-a-file-from-directory-outside-of-includes)